# Using a General Linear Model in SPSS to analyze two variables over time?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, spss

I'm struggling a little with an analysis I need to run in SPSS. I am analyzing the effect of openness on self-esteem over three timepoints. I want to make sure time is included as a factor in order to analyze the effect over time and I'm looking at a general linear model to accomplish that.

I have tried running separate linear regressions (ex: openness at month 3 and self esteem at month 3, openness at month 12 and self esteem at month 12) but I don't think those results will allow me to include time as a variable.

How do I accomplish this in SPSS?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CV! Separate regressions are not a great idea, as you have noticed. I think what you want to do is achievable via multilevel linear regression, in SPSS the Mixed models procedure (I assume Openness and self-esteem are considered to be continuous variables). [Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/01/a-brief-introduction-to-multilevel-modelling/) is a nice and brief intro to multilevel models.

You need to decide whether you treat time as continuous or categorical. If categorical, a multilevel regression predicting self-esteem from Openness and time would go something like this in SPSS:

```
MIXED selfesteem BY time WITH openness
  /FIXED=time openness
  /PRINT=SOLUTION TESTCOV #this line gives you the estimates to the output
  /RANDOM=INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(id) COVTYPE(VC). #id refers to participant id
```

So basically, the above code gives you the effects of time and openness on self-esteem while controlling for the non-independence of your observations.

If you want to include a random slope of participant for openness (i.e. get a slope of the relationship between openness and self-esteem for each participant separately, along with the overall coefficient), add openness to the last command line after "INTERCEPT". If you want time as continuous, put it after WITH command and remove the BY command. If you want the interaction effect between time and openness, you can add it after the FIXED command.

(Though to estimate the relationship between openness and self-esteem in a longitudinal dataset in which each is measured at each measurement does not necessarily require entering time into the model. You could just run a multilevel regression with openness predicting self-esteem.)